# Laravel/Vue JS - Cannot upload files from Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, laravel, vue.js, file-upload

I have a Laravel/Vue JS web app in which users are able to upload files and photos. Everything works fine until I try it in Android devices, where the axios call just hangs forever. Here's my code:

**Vue JS component**

```
<template>
    <span>
        <v-btn @click="pickFile">
            <small>{{ label }}</small>
        </v-btn>
        <input type="file" style="
            visibility:hidden;visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            width: 1px;
            height: 1px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;"
        ref="upload" :accept="accept" @change="onFilePicked"> // accept is defined in the element's props
    </span>
</template>
```

**Vue JS components' methods**

```
methods: {
    pickFile() {
        this.$refs.upload.click()
    },
    onFilePicked (e) {
        const files = e.target.files
        let elem = this
        let valid = true
        Event.$emit('uploading')
        if(files[0] !== undefined) {
            elem.fileName = files[0].name
            if(elem.fileName.lastIndexOf('.') <= 0) {
                return
            }

            const fr = new FileReader ()
            fr.readAsDataURL(files[0])

            fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file',files[0]);
                formData.append('document',elem.document);
                formData.append('pedido',elem.pedido);

                console.log(formData)

                axios.post('/files/upload-file',formData, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
                .then(response => {
                    //console.log(response);
                    Event.$emit('fileUploaded', response.data.filepath);
                    Event.$emit('alert', 'Tu archivo se guardó exitosamente');
                });
            });
        } else {
            elem.fileName = ''
        }
    }
},
```

In the backend, I use the `Input`, `Storage` and `File` facades to write to the disk, and save a `FileEntry` to my database. This whole process works perfectly fine on computers and iOS mobile devices, is there any special consideration for Android I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual reason, it had nothing to do with the Android devices as much as with the size of the file being uploaded. I added the proper `php.ini` configuration and will proceed to compress images on the fly.